# Android : Log cat analysis

Tags: android

I am getting prints from adb

> W/ActivityManager( 7107):
>
> I/PackageManager( 7107):
>
> D/NativeHelper( 7107):
>
> D/NativeLibraryHelper( 7107):

what does it meant by W I and D in the log cat prints ?

Answer (score 1):

V — Verbose (lowest priority)

D — Debug

I — Info

W — Warning

E — Error

F — Fatal

S — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)

```
Log.d("Tag","string");//debug
Log.v("Tag","string");//verbose 
Log.i("Tag","string");//info
Log.w("Tag","string");//warning
Log.e("Tag","string");//error
```

Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

W means warning level, I means information level and D means debugging level. These are the levels for priority to filter the logcat(because there're too many output). You can see [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

1. v(String, String) (verbose)
2. d(String, String) (debug)
3. i(String,
   String) (information)
4. w(String, String) (warning)
5. e(String, String)
   (error)

Use cases:

```
Log.d("Tag","my tag");//debug
Log.e("Tag","my tag");//error
```